# Is there any way to add pre-existing users to the "paid list" for new iOS in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, upgrade

I am in a tricky spot and I am trying to figure out the best way to proceed. I released an app a few months ago and have charged a few hundred people $.99 for it. I am now interested in making the app free with in-app purchases. How can I make it so that whoever has already paid for it, doesn't need to pay again? Can I programmatically "white list" them? And then just charge future users?

I have integrated with Game Center so I was toying around with the idea of checking for users on the leader boards already?

I can't make a separate app, I just was wondering if there was any API or route I could use to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a potential strategy:

1) Make your in-app purchase essentially a toggle that enables access to some features or resources in your app.

2) Change the name or location of some key file.  The database would be easiest (if you have one), but also look for user defaults or other saved files.

3) On launch of your new version, check to see if that older thing exists - if so, save a marker key into the keychain for the app (and if you renamed the database move the old version to the new name/location!).  The keychain is a nice place to put this as it persists between app installs.  I'm not sure if iCloud backs it up though.

4) Now when checking for a feature look for that marker key in the keychain in addition to asking Storekit if they have purchased the items you want unlocked for them.

5) In the UI block purchase and indicate they have already paid.

That's about the best you can do, they may have deleted the app altogether and in that case there's nothing you can do to help them... you may want to also make some kind of one-time use code that could unlock the feature in the same way (except that the code would be verified by your app against your server so that it could only be used when you allowed it), that way that you could help out individuals contacting you saying they had purchased the app before.  There's no way to verify that but it's just good customer service to let them have the upgrade anyway.